# Wordpress: Multiple keys for a query

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to apply a query, in order to display posts from different custom fields (with the same input - $id)

When testing the code below, I get the whole website to crash...

If I remove the name2 & name3 arrays, it works just fine.

Does anyone have a clue where I got stupid this time?

Thanks!

```
                        $example = new WP_Query(array(
                    'post_type' => 'example',
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'name1',
                            'value' => $id,
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'compare' => '='
                        ), 
                        array(
                            'key' => 'name2',
                            'value' => $id,
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'compare' => '='
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'name3',
                            'value' => $id,
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'compare' => '='
                        )

                    )
                ));
```

Comment: Whats the error generated when the site crashes?

Comment: Umm the whole website crashes and I get a 'lack of resources' error. Sound weird but I have no idea why it is happening